# How to get control id that just changed it value?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to create some function based on which control of 2 textbox that just changed , so I can call the appropriate function after that use js in asp.net.

To make it clear

I have 1 dropdownlist(ddl) and 3 texbox here they are

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tbTopUpAmount" placeholder="0" name="tbTopUpAmount" onblur="calculate()" onchange="calculate();setTBjustChanged(this)" onkeyup="calculate()" runat="server"/>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfCR" runat="server" /></div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tbAmountPaying" name="tbAmountPaying" placeholder="0"onblur="reverseCalculate()" onchange="reverseCalculate()" onkeyup="reverseCalculate();setTBjustChanged(this)" runat="server"/>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPaymentCurrency" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" onblur="showCRate2()" onChange="showCRate2();reCalculate()"></asp:DropDownList>
```

As you see all control have some event. 
This case about making currency conversion.
I want to get id from which textbox tbTopUpAmount or tbAmountPaying that just by user. So after that, I can apply command when dropdownlist selected to call calculate() or reverseCalculate() cause when dropdownlist selectedvaluechanged it call ajax then it update hfcr value. So if user input on tbTopUpAmount then currency rate change tbAmountpaying will update, and also conversely.

here my code

```
var TBjustchanged="";

        function setTBjustChanged(obj) {
            this.TBjustchanged = obj.id;
        }

        function reCalculate() {
            if (this.TBjustchanged == "tbTopUpAmount") {
                calculate();
            } else {
                reverseCalculate();
            }
        }
```

but didn't get control id, I don't know what's wrong

Comment: Your question isn't clear, try being more specific.

Comment: The information you're seeking is probably available in the event argument.

Comment: well @MotiAzu , I asked this question cause I guess this idea can  I apply to call apropriate function after the dropdown selected after many case, If you know more you can see at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032138/change-textbox-value-after-dropdownlist-change-multi-case

Comment: Ana, posts on SO are expected to be self-contained and preferably include question ("can you help me" *is not* a question for SO) and code you've tried. Linking to other posts/locations is ok to provide additional information not required to understand the problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for your edit, I will try to post better in future

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, create a variable to record a textbox when it changes then update it whenever the text box does change.

```
<input id="ineedtoknowwhenthischanges" onkeydown="whatchanged(this);">

var lastchangedtextbox;
function whatchanged(changedtextbox)
{
 lastchangedtextbox=changedtextbox.id;
}
```

Comment: I tried to apply this, and check it in chrome console ,dont know why  id undefined